# SQL Upsert DO Update does not update record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a temp table that I upsert to my main table, but when I run the below upsert command with update on conflict, the record I'm trying to update does not update at all. The schemas for main_table and temp are identical. Any ideas why this happens?

```
INSERT INTO main_table
SELECT *
FROM temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM main_table p
        WHERE t.core_id = p.core_id
)
ON CONFLICT (core_id) DO UPDATE 
SET project_urls = EXCLUDED.project_urls
```

Comment: I don't see how it would work, you're sub-select  is eliminating any record where `core_id` is equal so there will be no conflict.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. How can I fix this sub-select issue?

Comment: Remove the `WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`  section. The whole point of `ON CONFLICT` is that if there is an existing `core_id` it will take the action specified by the `DO`.  As with any change/new code start with `BEGIN;` so you can `ROLLBACK` if necessary.